# Silverstripe DropdownField not loading with loadDataFrom()

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a custom form for updating a database row. I pre-populate the field values using `$form->loadDataFrom( $data )`, where $data is an associative array of the field values.

This works great for all but the DropdownField; nothing is set as "selected".

Relevant code:

On the form subclass:

```
$fields = FieldList::create( 
... 
DropdownField::create('subscribed')->setSource(array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'))->setAttribute('class', 'default') 
);
```

In the controller:

```
$form->loadDataFrom($data);
```

I have verified that $data is a properly formatted associative array (after all, every other field gets the appropriate value).

The dropdown field will not set a selected value.

Comment: might be useful to see an output/dump of $data. Also, I personally had some issues with field names not starting with a capital (i.e. Subscribed) but this might not be related.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use true and false for source array keys:

```
DropdownField::create('subscribed')->setSource(array(
  true  => 'Yes',
  false => 'No'
))
```